# Neural network does not learn XOR (converges to 0.5 output)

Tags: c++, neural-network

I wrote a multilayer perceptron which should be able to learn XOR. However, whatever I do it converges to an output of 0.5 for inputs (1,1), (0,1) and (1,0). While for the input (0,0) it converges to zero. Does anyone have an idea where my mistake is?

Forward pass:

```
void MLP::feedforward() {
  for(int hidden = 0; hidden < nHidden; hidden++) {
  hiddenNeurons.at(hidden) = 0;

  for(int input = 0 ; input < nInput; input ++) {

    hiddenNeurons.at(hidden) += inputNeurons.at(input)*weightItoH(input,hidden);
  }
}

//Propagate towards the output layer
for(int i =0; i< nOutput; i ++) {
  outputNeurons.at(i) = 0;

  for(int j = 0; j <nHidden; j++) {
     outputNeurons.at(i) += hiddenNeurons.at(j) * weightHtoO(j,i);
  }

   outputNeurons.at(i) = sigmoid(outputNeurons.at(i));
 }
}
```

Backpropagation:

```
void MLP::backPropagation(int i) {
  float learningRate = 0.75;
  float error = desiredOutput[i] - outputNeurons[0];

// Calculate delta for output layer
for(int i=0; i<nOutput; i++) {
   outputDelta.at(i) = error * dersigmoid(outputNeurons[i]);
}

//Calculate delta for hidden layer
 for(int i = 0; i < nHidden; i++) {
  hiddenDelta.at(i) = 0;//zero the values from the previous iteration

  //add to the delta for each connection with an output neuron
  for(int j = 0; j < nOutput; j ++) {
      hiddenDelta.at(i) += outputDelta.at(j) * weightHtoO(i,j) ;
  }
 }

//Adjust weights Input to Hidden
for(int i = 0; i < nInput; i ++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < nHidden; j ++) {
      weightItoH(i,j) += learningRate * hiddenDelta.at(j);
  }
}

//Adjust weights hidden to Output
for(int i = 0; i < nOutput; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < nHidden; j ++) {
      weightHtoO(j,i) += learningRate * outputDelta.at(i) * hiddenNeurons.at(j);
  }
}

}
```

Input

```
nInputPatterns = 4;

inputPatterns.assign(nInputPatterns, vector<int>(2));

inputPatterns[0][0] = 1;
inputPatterns[0][1] = 1;
inputPatterns[1][0] = 0;
inputPatterns[1][1] = 1;
inputPatterns[2][0] = 1;
inputPatterns[2][1] = 0;
inputPatterns[3][0] = 0;
inputPatterns[3][1] = 0;

desiredOutput = {0,1,1,0};
```

Sigmoid function and macro's

```
#define sigmoid(value)  (1/(1+exp(-value)));
#define dersigmoid(value) (value*(1-value));

//Macro's
#define weightItoH(input,hidden) weightsIH.at(nInput*hidden+input)
#define weightHtoO(hidden,output) weightsHO.at(nHidden*output+hidden)
```

C++ file: http://pastebin.com/8URZAHSy
Header file: http://pastebin.com/YiMXpmZX

Comment: Can you shrink down you code to a small example and put it inline in the question instead of providing links?

Comment: @Hayt: No - you cannot write a trainable neural network in a small C++ example.

Comment: I added the important parts in the code above. I will also add the complete files using pastebin. Thanks a lot for having a look.

Comment: @MSalters yeah I would have guessed. I just wanted to nudge in the direction as to why this question gets downvoted etc. If you cannot shrink it down to a certain degree it may be too broad for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

There's no random initialization. This is needed to break the symmetry; else all your neurons learn the exact same values. That's effectively the same as having one neuron, and one neuron is insufficient for XOR.

Comment: So the weights need to be initialised randomly? Between for instance -0.5 and 0.5?

Comment: If I do this, the outputs get to: 0.5 0.5 0.8 0.0. Where for XOR it should be 0 1 1 0. This is with 100000 epochs. Am I correct that with 3 hidden nodes, it should be able to learn XOR without a bias?

Comment: Definitely an improvement, but yes 3 nodes should be enough.

Comment: Do you maybe have any idea why the network still does not find the correct solution?

Comment: @Stefan1993: Not directly, but I know how to debug it. I know that in training, I get errors `(+0.5, 0,5, -0.2, 0)` and these should propagate back to both weight layers. This should update the weights and move them in the right direction, something that is debuggable with just 2 inputs, 3 hidden nodes and one output (so 2x3 and 3x1 weights)

Comment: Ok! Is it better to use -1 for 0's in the input? Since now you will always have sigmoid(0)=0.5 as activation in the hidden nodes. Or is that problematic due to the use of a sigmoid activation function (always positive)?